# How to slice dataframe smartly?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with python especially `pandas` module. I am slicing in this way `dfps7 = dfps5.iloc[:,[1,4,5,7,8,9,10]]` and it's working. But I want to know the smart way of representing the continuous part as like `4,5,7,8,9,10` as `4:10`. When I tried like `dfps7 = dfps5.iloc[:,[1,4:10]]` and this is not working. Looking forward for the smartest solution.

Comment: have a look at [np.r_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html). something like this might work for you: ``df.iloc[:, np.r_[1, 4:10]]``

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy. It's working fine